# Proper way to implement async tasks for simple API calls? (android)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I 'm a new programmer working on my first android app. I ran into a "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException," did some research and realised I need to do network related stuff using async. However, all of the help I found online involved creating classes for each task.
 However, I'm just working with simple one line API calls, and many of them. I don't think it would be very efficient to have tens of asynctask classes, one for each of them. What is the proper way to work with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imho there is two ways. Create own Async Task which will takes address as parameter and will have some interface to pass action you need to do after.
Second way is to use default java threading mechanism. Example:

```
new Thread(
    new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
        //api call
    }
}).start();
```